# Alterar tipo de todos os campos da tabela

Tags: mysql

Tem como alterar todos os campos da minha tabela para `VARCHAR`? Tenho uma tabela com bastantes campos e queria que de forma automática todos os campos fossem alterados para tipo `VARCHAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um script em PHP

```html
$tabela = "nomedatabelaparamodificar"

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tabela");

while ($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

$array[] = $lista[0];


}


foreach ($array as $valor){
 
 
 mysql_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE $tabela MODIFY $valor VARCHAR(50)");
 
}
```

Tente isso!

Comment: Obrigado pela solução =)

Comment: Desculpe, houve uma confusao...o script que fiz altera as tabelas...ja corrigo...

Comment: Pronto, corrigi e fiz umas melhorias....